# VNC Multi device keyboard mouse input remote user

Tags: remote, desktop, vnc

i'm not sure this is within the realms of possibility, but I think it maybe, and I really want to see if something like this exists, or may be possible.

Ok, so what I want is to be able to have two (or more) simultaneous inputs (keyboard & mouse (including remote)) on one instance of windows (I've got win 7), collaborating on a single document, lets say a powerpoint presentation (2010 version).

Now I know there are technologies such as VNC, which allow you to take control of a PC, for instance to allow remote desktop assistance/support; but as far as i'm aware, you can only control the existing mouse/keyboard, not allow both the existing keyboard and another keyboard to be used remotely concurrently.

I'm unsure of this second point, but I believe you can have two mice plugged into the same computer, and have two inputs.

Can these technologies be married up? does this already exist somewhere? - I've already seen something called 'teamplayer' but this seems quite dodgy, can't get any instructions out of this company on how to run the program!...

Anyway, any help would be much appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: apologies about that, ok, how do i migrate this question over to superuser?

Comment: The moderators should do that for you shortly. :)